# How to make a TextView move from a screen center to its location in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

The animotion is that a `TextView` move from the screen center to its location,at the same time,the size change from zero to normal.
I have knew to use the `TranslateAnimation` and the `ScaleAnimation`,but I don't know make sure the poist,so I can't let it move from the center to its location.
What shuold I do?

```
TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(0,(mWidth / 2)- strSize / 2, 0, ((mHeight / 2) - strHeigth));
strHeigth: the TextView heigth;
strSize : the TextView width
mWidth : the screen width;
mHeight : the screeen heigth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation((mWidth / 2)- strSize / 2,
 0,
 (mHeight / 2) - strHeigth,
 0);
```

try with this code for translate anim

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are having